# Не сохраняется с первого раза ckeditor

Tags: javascript, api

Не сохраняется с первого раза ckeditor. Смотрел данную тему на форуме, не смог разобраться.

Пишу здесь сам JS код, надеюсь его будет достаточно!:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function call() {
      var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save.php',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#save').html(data);
          },              
        });    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Для вставки и форматирования кода на ruSO есть кнопки на панели инструментов. Нужно их использовать.

Comment: Честно пробовал, ещё хуже получалось!

Answer (score 0):

текст, введенный в редакторе, находится в отдельном теге.
Нужно перед submit перенести его в ваш input или textarea
Вынуть текст можно методом .editor.getData()